# CSS style from deploy build is different than in dev build

Tags: html, css, reactjs, deployment

Everything looks good and works fine in my react app dev build, but some css styles aren't being correctly applied to the production build i host on my github pages through gh-pages npm package (through this guide https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages)

this is my hosted app: https://arthwr.github.io/little-lemon-app/

The problem with mobile version hamburger button.
It works like this: it applies .openMenu class to 2 elements (parent div and nav element) to apply some css styles. However menu that is supposed to be hidden on left , is seen and by the look of dev tools css styles for default behaviour aren't being loaded correctly or not switching for some reason. Class is added and changed correctly though. I attached 2 screenshots so its seen how i want it to look like and how it looks and works correctly on my dev version.
I also attached CSS snapshot for the elements that have this problem :

```
.navContainer
.navContainer.openMenu
.nav
.nav.openMenu
```

```
[Styles for nav menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zD1dt.png)
[How it looks in deploy build (incorrect)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEbuS.png)
[Devbuild correct state (inactive)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK8YR.png)
[Devbuild correct state (active)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Mflc.png)
```

**UPDATE:**

after i looked through minified version of css i found out that somehow deploy build is concatinating css classes into 1, but ignoring styles for default and not loading them (without openMenu class) :

```
.Nav_navContainerGhavJ,
.Nav_navContainerGhavJ.Nav_openMenuL+8i0,
.Nav_navp72ig,
.Nav_navp72ig.Nav_openMenuL+8i0 {
  @media screen and (max-width: 852px) {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

so i see the problem but i don't know how to solve this. I also tried to change class names but it didn't help

Comment: I see that your `browserslist` has different settings for prod-env and dev-env. Have you tried to set prod settings for dev environment? The link: https://github.com/Arthwr/little-lemon-app/blob/main/package.json

Comment: @Eugene 
Hi! Thank you for responding! 
I tried to your suggestion and changed `browserlist` settings of dev environment to be the same as production settings. However there were no noticable changes in dev build (i only checked the issue with menu). Everything worked fine in dev build as before and i assume nothing should change in prod as well (still not working correctly).